# Initial call to /oidc/me provides null address response

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I am utilizing the `/oidc/me` endpoint to obtain address information (https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/oauth-and-openid-connect/details/#/User%20Info). I'm observing that when calling the endpoint for a given user, the `address` property in the response will contain null values on the first call to the endpoint. Then, on subsequent calls the `address` property will be populated with correct details. I've observed that the timing between the first
(failed, with missing address info) call and second (successful, with address info) calls can be less than a minute apart.

What can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

Edit to provide the sequence of API requests:

1. `/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/auth`
   `&scope=openid profile email`
   `&claims=`

```
{
  "userInfo": {
    "https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/shares": null,
    "https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/customer_identifier": null,
    "address": null
}
```

2. `/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/token`
3. `/a/consumer/api/v0/oidc/me`

Answer (score 0):

We're unable to reproduce this problem based on the above description. When we try it ourselves we get the `address` property as expected.

Can you provide a sequence of API requests (starting from initial authentication) that result in this behavior?

The `x-request-id` from the headers is also helpful (see https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/overview/troubleshooting/).

Comment: My understanding from the article you noted is that `x-request-id` will be returned only when the API returns an error response (500?). As far as I know the responses our application receives are always 200.

Comment: The `x-request-id` is also included in successful responses. It tends to be the most useful for error responses but is also in success responses.